# Is the source of ActivePerl available?

Tags: perl, activeperl

I searched the ActivePerl web site, but didn't get the source download. Is it available to the public? I got some crash in ActivePerl and tried to make quick fix on the source if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the patch used to create ActivePerl from Perl and the patched version are available from http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePerl/releases/.

Alternatively, the source for regular Perl is available for download and installation from CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl. Be sure to read `README.win32`.

Answer (score 5):

If you go to http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePerl/releases/ you can see a diff against the official release ( 5.14.2.1402/ActivePerl-5.14.2.1402-295342-diff.txt    ) as well as a source release.  Diffs for  ancient releases like 5.6/5.8 are no longer listed at this website, though you might find them archived elsewhere. CPAN.org lists all official perl releases. Like others mentioned, there was never a 2.8 version of perl, see `perldoc perlhist`